# Render angular's html from the variable on scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm aware of security implications related to my request, but I need to allow a special super admin group of users an ability to create and evaluate angular html contained within variable on current $scope

Here is an example [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/094LxXb6MFEIcHINPT9H?p=preview):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.15"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-init="variable = 3; content = '{{ variable }}'">
    <div>
      The value of $scope.variable === "{{ variable }}"
    </div>
    <div>
      The value of $scope.content === "{{ content }}"
    </div>
    <br>
    <div>
    The value of $scope.content is <b>ng-model</b>'ed via the following textarea:<br>
    </div>

    <textarea rows="3" ng-model="content"></textarea>

    <div style="border: 1px solid black">
      Instead of rendering the value of the $scope.content field which is currently equal to "{{ content }}" I need to render compiled and evaluated value which should be equal to "{{ variable }}"
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `<body ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-init="variable = 3; content = variable">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a directive that uses the `$compile` service to do this for you.

Here is what I came up with, and [a fork of your Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/AHCCeL5dX5snvuo67JNW?p=preview) to show that it works.

```
app.directive('compile', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      var prevScope;
      scope.$watch(attrs.compile, function(newVal, oldVal) {
        // create a span (an inline element) so we have an actual DOM node to
        // set the innerHTML of.
        var newElem = document.createElement('span');
        newElem.innerHTML = newVal;
        // clean up first
        if (prevScope) {
          prevScope.$destroy();
          prevScope = null;
        }
        // clear out the contents of this element
        elem.empty();
        // and replace it with the raw (uncompiled) node
        elem[0].appendChild(newElem);
        // now the node is in the DOM so we can compile it
        // but we want to use a try..catch because the user
        // might be in the middle of typing a new expression,
        // but the syntax right now is not valid so the
        // expression parser will throw an error.
        try {
          // compile the node in the DOM with a child of the existing scope
          prevScope = scope.$new();
          $compile(newElem)(prevScope);
        } catch (e) { /* don't need to do anything here */ }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Btw. the code creates a memory leak when `compile` changes, here I've added another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29190471/angular-js-compile-service-causes-watch-memory-leak

Comment: @Lu4 Well spotted, sir! I fixed it in that other question, and for future readers of this answer, you should know that I edited my answer here to include the fixed version as well.