# AngularJS : How to properly recompile an element directive that has input fields with ngModel and input directives binded without memory leak

Tags: angularjs, validation, input, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

**Background**
I looked and found nothing like this so I have been trying to create a reusable input wrapper element directive that can be dropped into a regular angular form, interact with the ngModel and Form controllers properly and be able to take the same validation directives that a regular input takes (e.g., required, ng-minlength, ...) and any other custom directives and apply them to a child input element it contains.

Basically the idea is that this directive is a more advanced form of the regular input (provides bootstrap 3 validation highlighting, validation icon inside the textbox itself, and more).

**Problems:**
It should be possible to dynamically decorate the child input with list of directives passed into the wrapper directive.

1. Recompiling the directive helps attach/detach directives to the
   child input, but somehow the Watchers on the main scope keep
   increasing (memory leak)? I believe I need to destroy the scope of
   the directive and renew it to solve this problem but I haven't
   figured out a way to do that without causing digest errors.
2. This is likely related to #1, but the form itself also shows signs
   of improper cleanup. The $error field that corresponds to errors
   would show multiple error objects related to "required" after you
   inject a few different directives, showing that each time the
   directive is recompiled, it leaves some residue on the parent form.

Full Demo: http://codepen.io/b3hrooz/pen/aORzrK

**Wrapper Directive:**

```
.directive("validatableInput", ['$compile', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    require: ["^form","?ngModel"],
    replace: false,
    templateUrl: "validation-input-template.htm",
    scope: {
      label: '@',
      id: '@',
      type: '@',
      bindModel: '=',
      name: '@',
      validationModel: '=',
      directives: '&'
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, controllers) {
      var inputElem = elem.find('input'), 
          newInputElem = null,
          formController = controllers[0];

      scope.type = scope.type || 'text';
      scope.$watch('directives()', function(newDirectives, oldDirectives) {
           newInputElem = inputElem.clone();
          for (var directive in newDirectives) {
            newInputElem.attr(directive, newDirectives[directive] ? newDirectives[directive] : directive);
          }
          //  formController.$removeControl(scope.name);
          elem.find('input').replaceWith(newInputElem);

          $compile(elem.contents())(scope);

      }, true);

    }
  };
}]);
```

**Directive Template (removed irrelevant parts):**

```
<script type='text/ng-template' id='validation-input-template.htm'>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group has-feedback" data-ng-class="{'has-success':focus && validationModel.$valid ,'has-error':validationModel.$dirty && validationModel.$invalid , 'has-warning':validationModel.$pending}">
        <label class="control-label" for='{{id}}-input'>{{label}}</label>
        <input type="{{type}}" class="form-control" id="{{id}}-input" data-ng-model="bindModel" ng-focus="focus=true;" name="{{name}}">
    </div>
  </script>
```

**Usage:**

```
<form name='aForm'>
          <validatable-input label='User Name' bind-model='main.userName' name='uname' validation-model='aForm.uname' id='some-id-2' directives='main.injectedDirectives'> </validatable-input>
          <validatable-input label='ID Number' type='text' bind-model='main.idNumber' name='idNum' validation-model='aForm.idNum' id='some-id-3' directives='{"required":"", "digit-only":"","prime":""}'> </validatable-input>
</form>
```

**Main Controller that handles changing of the list of directives that need to be applied to input:**

```
.controller("MainController", ['$scope', function($scope) {
  this.LIST = {
    'required': '',
    'ng-minlength': '3',
    'ng-maxlength': '8',
    'digit-only': '',
    'even':'',
     'ng-model-options':'{ debounce: 2000 }'
  };
  this.injectedDirectives = {};

  this.injectDirective = function() {
    for (var key in this.LIST) {
      if (this.LIST.hasOwnProperty(key) && !this.injectedDirectives.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        this.injectedDirectives[key] = this.LIST[key];
        return;
      }
    }
    this.injectedDirectives= {};
  };
}]);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular JS $compile service causes $watch memory leak](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29190471/angular-js-compile-service-causes-watch-memory-leak)